# Pushed Authorization Request lifetime in OpenID Connect

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, object-lifetime

As we can see here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-par#section-2.2
pushed authorization request lifetime should be between 5 and 600 seconds.

So assume that it's 60 seconds. Then client redirects user to authorization endpoint and... user is not logged in. So authorization endpoint redirect the user to endpoint with login page with request_uri as query param. The user logs in, login page redirect user to authorization endpoint with request_uri from query param. Probably, if lifetime was about 10s the request_uri is expired now (and what's more it's used more than once). So how can we handle the flow when user is not authenticated while he is redirected to authorization endpoint and we use PAR?

I know that can be 600 seconds also, but the recommendations say that this lifetime should be as short as possible. Therefore, it seems to me that I misunderstand how PAR works. I don't think even 10 minutes is enough because what if user currently doesn't have account at the identity provider or there is MFA used?

Please tell me, how PAR really works.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a browser based app implementing this flow:

**STEP 1**

The browser wants to begin a login and calls its backend. The backend sends a standard Open ID Connect request like this to the authorization server:

```
POST https://login.example.com/oauth/authorize/par

Authorization: Basic czZCaFo3RmpmcDBa:QnIxS3REUmJuZbUl3

client_id=myclient&
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F&
scope=openid%20profile&
response_type=code&
response_mode=jwt&
code_challenge=WQ4Y4CQpO8W6VtELopzYHdNg&
code_challenge_method=S256&
state=NFBljlVuB1GDjgGARmqDcxtHhV8
```

The authorization server saves the OIDC request details. Note also that the authorization header includes the client secret, which is one of the key features of PAR - the client authenticates before the redirect to the authorization server. So a malicious app cannot redirect a user with your client ID, since they do not know the secret.

**STEP 2**

The browser then uses the request URI. The short time you mention is only for this redirect and does not impact user login time:

```
https://login.example.com/oauth/authorize?
client_id=myclient&
request_uri=urn:ietf:params:oauth:request_uri:7d353fc8-9b94-488f-8c61-cf7cc1dfef9e"
```

**STEP 3**

The user logs in, and in some cases that might take a minute or so, as you say. Then a response is returned to the browser:

```
https://www.example.com/callback?response=eyJra...
```

In this example I am receiving the response as a JWT, using a related standard called JARM that can be used in conjunction with PAR. The JWT looks like this and could contain an error response in some cases:

```json
{
  "exp": 1629112321,
  "iss": "https://login.example.com",
  "aud": "myclient",
  "iat": 1629112301,
  "purpose": "authz_response",
  "code": "abcdef",
  "state": "12345abcdef"
}
```

If you don't use JARM you will instead receive `code`, `state` and `error` fields in the browser URL. The flow finishes with the usual authorization code grant POST, to swap the code for tokens.

**SUMMARY**

All of the above is designed to prevent man in the browser attacks. Eg a malicious party cannot alter any fields in flight. Extra security is therefore added to the standard code flow.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but check this out: I have redirect_uri with lifetime equal to 60seconds. I can use it at authorization endpoint, but if user isn't logged in then he is redirected to login page. Login page contains something like redirect url and this is url to authorization endpoint with parameters that we sent at the beginning (so request_uri is the same). Assume that user logs in in 70 seconds. Now request_uri is expired, so when user is redirected back to authorization endpoint he should get an error (request_uri expired). What should we do in this case?

Comment: It doesn't work like that. The timing between step 1 and step 2 will be in the region of 100ms. The redirect to the authorization server will maybe take a second, after which the request_uri is never used again. The steps above are followed every time a login or single sign occurs, so next time there will be a different request_uri. After a request_uri is processed, the authorization server sets a cookie, then may present a login page, but it will not contain a redirect url.

Comment: So login page should create new request_uri based on data from request_uri saved in a cookie and then redirect user to authorization endpoint with new request_uri? Did I understand this well?

Comment: Or maybe can we use a 10 minute (long life) request_uri with PKCE? The par request contains something like par_challenge, and you need to add par_verifier in the authorization endpoint. What do you think? OIDC allows something like this?

Comment: Nope - the only thing an app can do is use the inputs and outputs from my main answer. In step 2 it hands control over to the authorization server, which manages the login page for you. When the login page has finished, the authorization server will redirect back to your app, using the redirect_uri value in step 1 from my main answer. Apps cannot customise this core behaviour, and must follow the standards, which have been designed very carefully, for best security.

Comment: Ok, so: 1. Send request to PAR. 2. Redirect user with received request_uri to authorization endpoint. 3. User is not logged in, set cookie that determines user isn't logged (e.g. loggedIn: false) then redirect user to login page. 4. User logs in, he is redirected to redirect_uri (client callback endpoint) and JARM contains property that say redirection to authorization endpoints is needed. 5. User is redirected to authorization endpoint with new request_uri and get back to redirect_uri with JARM response. Did i understand correctly?

Comment: I edited my question a bit. I hope now my problem is more readable.

Comment: The login page does not use the request_uri value. It has no need for it. What makes you think it does? Instead, the login page just posts user credentials to the server. The authorization server validates credentials then typically writes a redirect response that returns the result to the app, eg by setting a 302 status code with this response header: ```location: https://web.example.com?code=xxx&state=yyy```.

Comment: After all, the login page doesn't redirect to the client, but the authorization endpoint does it. So the login page must redirect to the authorization endpoint after successful login, but request_uri may already have expired by that time.

Comment: I have an idea: https://pastebin.com/4AgE91rT is it a good solution to this problem?