# Restrict untrusted clients to access an OpenID Connect authorize endpoint

Tags: openid-connect, authorize

In OpenID Connect (as well as generally in OAuth 2.0) the /authorize endpoint is unauthenticated.
The client_id parameter can identify the client application, but does not authenticate it. So the /authorize endpoint can be called by unauthorized people replaying an old call containing valid parameters.
I need this because authenticating a user in my service will generate a cost, and I don't want the service to be abused by people copying a valid /authorize URL and calling it later without any form of protection.
Does OAuth / OIDC have a standard way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Pushed Authorization Requests (PAR) are a newer standard that address this concern, and changes the OpenID Connect flow. See this [other recent answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73916585/pushed-authorization-request-lifetime-in-openid-connect) for details. Note that it requires a confidential client that can provide a secret.

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud Signature Consortium has introduced the "account_token" parameter in their API specification to achieve this goal (see section 8.3.1 from https://cloudsignatureconsortium.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/CSC_API_V1_1.0.4.0.pdf), but I'd like to know if there's a more standard or common way.