# Can authorize endpoint return login page? OpenID Connect

Tags: openid-connect, authorize

Considering on a solution to my earlier problem ([Pushed Authorization Request lifetime in OpenID Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73916585/pushed-authorization-request-lifetime-in-openid-connect)), I figured that PAR could only work if the authorization endpoint provided a login page and not another endpoint. Is it correct that the authorization endpoint provides a login page? It will have to use POST method to login user and OIDC says POST should allow the same as GET. That's why I don't know what to do.

Comment: Why do you need to use PAR? PAR is a bit more advanced use-case.

Answer (score 0):

without PAR, you typically make a GET request to the **/authorize** endpoint, and when your client application gets the authorization code back, it makes a separate POST request to the **/token** endpoint to retrieve the final tokens.

Comment: Yes, but I have to use PAR.

Comment: What is the actual question? With PAR, you first in advance, upload the initial authentication request as a POST, then you redirect the user to the actual authentication page, and then you use the auth code to request the tokens. So the timeout for the first initial POST request should not be that long, as it is more or less an API call. That's how I understand it.

Comment: The question is: Is it true that to use PAR you need a login page displayed in authorize endpoint when user is not logged in. Otherwise, I can't imagine the authorization_code flow with PAR with login page on another endpoint. When login and authorization are separate, what should the login page do after user login? After all, the request_uri sent earlier in the request is already expired.

Comment: I see PAR as just a split of the initial /authorize request into two parts, as a way to keep the authorization details as part of the URL. Of course you need to present the user with a login screen in the second step. But first you "upload" the authorization that you do, then do redirect the user to do the actual authentication/login.

Comment: So when using PAR, the authorization endpoint redirects the user to the login page with the query parameter (or cookie) containing the client's redirect_uri, then after successful login, is it supposed to create a response with code and state and redirect to redirect_uri? It seems to me that this is duplicating the work of the authorization endpoint.

Comment: without PAR, the initial request parameter is sent in the URL , and for security and to be able to post more data, with PAR, you upload it as a POST in the body. And you get a "reference" back to that upload. Then you can redirect the user to the authentication page. Yes, there's one extra request being made, and "some" more work for the auth server. But this is only during login and if that takes 100ms more , then that is ok. After you get the tokens, then everything is the same.

Comment: Yes, I really understand it. Instead of parameters I just send reference to these parameters (request_uri). It seems to me that I can't explain what I mean, so I ilustrated my problem here: https://imgur.com/a/vg166Cl

Comment: The login page, authorization endpoint, and par endpoint is all the same service. The login page is part of the authorization endpoint. After successfull login/authentication, the user is redirected back to the client application, to the redirecturl hard-coded in the authentication service.

Comment: So login page is displayed at authorization endpoint? If not, how login page can know client_id? May should it be setted in cookie when user is redirected to login page from authorization endpoint?

Comment: Yes, that is the big idea with openid connect, you authenticate/loin at a central location, just like google, when you login to gmail.com, you are redirected to accounts.google.com   to do the actual authentication. The Client_Id/secret is registered/configured in the auth service in advance.

Comment: I know it's done on one location, but I don't know if its done on one endpoint also. Must be login form displayed at authorization endpoint when we use PAR? If not, what login page e.g. /account should do when user logs in? It should redirect back to authorization endpoint (but how if login page doesnt contain request_uri), or rather to client callback (but how login page at e.g. /account endpoint can know redirect_uri)? Should authorization endpoint create cookie with it while redirecting to login page?